# Univocity parser : Disable auto formatting

Tags: csv, univocity, csv-parser

I am using Univocity parser(2.9.1) to read and write csv.
I have following issues

1. When a java object has a value, for ex. September 8 , in the generated CSV i see 8-Sep or 9/7/2023. How to disable auto formatting. I want to write java object value as is in the CSV without any auto-formatting and auto-correction.

Please advise.